# How to apply grunge texture in this node settings

Tags: node-editor

I'm trying to apply a grunge texture to this node set up, I cant figure out the correct configuration.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure about your current setup, but about your "grunge" texture, could you please show a picture of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: I Have those nods set up (after seeing a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrcHOMUWJbI) because they make a swirl pattern like a frisbee has. But I want to add some dirt grunge to it. 

https://ibb.co/yNG7B1T
https://ibb.co/G7TYCkW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate your current node setup, make it darker (and less glossy etc), mix it with the previous node setup through a *Mix Shader*, use the grunge image texture as a factor in this *Mix Shader*, it should give something like that:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, once again!